# Magento 1.9 {{var payment_html}} alternative

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail, variables

I'm writing my own function for sending emails. 
In the Magento email template, there's a variable `{{var payment_html}}` which I need to convert to $order object. The question is how can I get the content of `payment_html` from `$order` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot the payment html directly form the order because there is a block involved.
You can generate the html like this:
Let's say `$order` is your order object.

```
$paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
                ->setIsSecureMode(true);
$paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($order->getStoreId());
$paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
```

BUt if you want you can attache the payment html to the order object after generating it.

```
$order->setPaymentHtml($paymentBlockHtml);
```

and you can read it from the order object after that with

```
$order->getPaymentHtml();
```